# SQL - Finding Nearby Places with DISTINCT? (Maps API)

Tags: mysql, sql, maps

I have a separate table in MYSQL with the addresses of the users containing the location information (latitude and longitude), each user being able to have more than one registered address. My goal is that when you perform a search for a location, all users who are closest to that location are listed.

The problem is that I can not do DISTINCT so that each user is listed only once in SELECT. I searched deeper and saw that GROUP BY could solve the problem. It does indeed group users by preventing repetition, however it does not maintain the correct order that would be the shortest distance.

This case can be easily seen in the Maps documentation, but DISTINCT is not done.

Result without GROUP BY:

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
   2         1        MARIA         5
   3         2        KEVIN         6
   1         1        MARIA         8
   4         2        KEVIN         10
```

Result with GROUP BY:

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
    1         1        MARIA         8
    3         2        KEVIN         6
```

When should it be ...

```
ID_PLACE | ID_USER | NAME_USER | DISTANCE
   2         1        MARIA         5
   3         2        KEVIN         6
```

With GROUP BY, sorting by distance seems to be ignored and is apparently being done by PLACE_ID.

My SELECT is this:

```
SELECT id, user_id,
    (6371 *
     Cos (radians (-30.053831))
     * Cos (radians (lat))
     * Cos (radians (lng) -radians (-51.191810))
     + Sin (radians (-30.053831))
     * Sin (radians (lat))
     )
    ) AS distance
    FROM places
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING distance < 25
    ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Comment: É estranho porque, sem o GROUP BY funciona perfeitamente, porém não quero que os usuários se repitam...

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT id,
       user_id,
       (6371 * Cos (radians (-30.053831)) * Cos (radians (lat)) * Cos (radians (lng) -radians (-51.191810)) + Sin (radians (-30.053831)) * Sin (radians (lat)) ) ) AS distance
FROM places
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY (6371 * Cos (radians (-30.053831)) * Cos (radians (lat)) * Cos (radians (lng) -radians (-51.191810)) + Sin (radians (-30.053831)) * Sin (radians (lat)) ) ASC;
```

Comment: It continues giving in the same ... When it is grouped the order is impaired. Apparently only the first record (PLACE_ID) of each user is listed.

Comment: then you can keep whole query in temp and then order the distance, but it will take time to load the data